# Injecting Xamarin Forms view into Android View

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms `ContentView` with it's UI defined in XAML.
This view should be dynamically added to the root view of the app when a certain custom renderer is being used.

For iOS this is working perfectly, but on Android I'm not getting the correct UI like it is defined in XAML. Just getting 1 big rectangle and nothing else.

Code used in iOS

```
public static UIView ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view, CGRect size)
{
    var renderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(view);
    renderer.NativeView.Frame = size;
    renderer.NativeView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
    renderer.NativeView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
    renderer.Element.Layout(size.ToRectangle());
    var nativeView = renderer.NativeView;
    nativeView.SetNeedsLayout();

    return nativeView;
}
```

Then in the custom renderer

```
var rect = new CGRect(0, 0, 250, 55);
_overlayTabView = Helpers.ConvertFormsToNative(new OverlayTabView(), rect);
var result = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
var x = (result.Width / 2) - 125;
var y = (result.Height - (55 + 20));
_overlayTabView.Frame = new CGRect(x, y, 250, 55);
RootView.AddSubView(_overlayTabView);
```

So this is ok!
Now Android

```
public static Android.Views.View ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view, Rectangle size)
{
    var renderer = Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(view, Android.App.Application.Context);
    var nativeView = renderer.View;
    renderer.Tracker.UpdateLayout();
    var layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
    nativeView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
    view.Layout(size);
    nativeView.Layout(0, 0, (int)view.WidthRequest, (int)view.HeightRequest);

    return nativeView;
}
```

And in the custom renderer

```
var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 250, 55);
_overlayView = Helpers.ConvertFormsToNative(new OverlayTabView(), rect);
((ViewGroup)CurrentView.Parent).AddView(_overlayView);
```

This does create the correct control it seems when I debug, but when it's being added to the UI, I only get 1 big empty rectangle.

Not sure where the problem resides, so maybe it would be great if someone can point me to some sort of basic example of this principle. That way I can tailor that to my needs, because the XAML ContentView also has controls in it that use custom renderers themselves.
Now just using this ContentView in a regular ContentPage works fine on both platforms.

Comment: Did you check any of these repositories [Forms2Native](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native) and [Native2Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms) ?

Comment: Also you can read these posts [Embedding Xamarin.Forms into a Xamarin Native App](https://montemagno.com/embedding-xamarinforms-into-a-xamarin-native-app/) or official doc [Xamarin.Forms in Xamarin Native Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms)

Comment: Yeah followed those too... but scenario here is a bit different ( or I'm not reading the docs right? ). I'm trying to add a subpart and not change the whole page. Meaning first the source is a ContentView instead of Page and the Target is not a full fragment. But I need to inject into an existing subview.

Comment: Could be this technique could function for my case too, but I was unable to make it work. Hence the stacko question. So anyone have a good example?

Comment: Did you try change the Context namespace to `var renderer = Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(view, Android.Content.Context);` ? Also the Rectangle on the method params are `Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle` or `System.Drawing.Rectangle` ?

Comment: I tried passing the context of the custom renderer and that has same result. Your suggestion gives a compiler error stating that the input parameter is a type and not an actual context

Comment: It is a Xamarin forms rectangle

Comment: Other idea could be add some container like `LinearLayout` and insert your `nativeView` inside it and then return the `LinearLayout`.